# Rotate keyframe animation not smooth

Tags: css, css-transforms

I can't tell why my loading icon animation is laggy. It doesn't seem to be hardware accelerated. I believe this is a standard way of doing this, so I'm a bit confused.

```
.is-loading
  color: transparent
  pointer-events: none
  position: relative
  &:after
    -webkit-animation: spinAround 750ms infinite linear
    animation: spinAround 750ms infinite linear
    border: 2px solid
    border-radius: 100%
    content: ""
    display: block
    left: 50%
    margin-left: -8px
    margin-top: -8px
    top: 50%
    position: absolute
    height: 16px
    width: 16px
    border-color: transparent white white white


@-webkit-keyframes spinAround
  from
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  to
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg)
    transform: rotate(359deg)

@keyframes spinAround
  from
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  to
    transform: rotate(359deg)
```

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/kmj2318/pen/BPLjPM

It looks really bad on my own page but it might be hard to tell it's laggy on codepen. If you open your web inspector and hover over the html elements you'll see it similarly to how it does for me.

Comment: why not 360deg? and it seems to be fine

Comment: I believe 360 degrees is the same as 0 degrees, so you would have two frames at the same point, but it's probably not even noticeable.

Comment: this is the trick for infinite,  the first state equal to last state

Comment: I changed it to 360 but it doesn't fix it. I've been looking at how https://plasso.com/login does this. If you add the class loading to the log in button, it will show the animation. I have not been able to get it to lag the way mine is.

Comment: the 360 wasn't for the fix, it's was a simple comment :)

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I couldn't resist playing around with your codepen: https://codepen.io/RobMo/pen/WKGxbO. Maybe it's helpful for something.

Answer (score 0):

To force the hardware acceleration, you should use `translateZ(0)` at the end of other transformations:

```
from
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateZ(0)
to
    transform: rotate(359deg) translateZ(0)
```